# Saving Loading and Running Machine Learning Model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, data-science

Hey I am new to Data Science, I created a Sentiment Analysis Model with keras. It takes a lot of time to train the model and test it eventually. Is there a way to save pretrained model and run it with the tests from user input?

My program basically creates sentiment analysis model and after that it creates a user command line interface:

Here is my code after creating the model:

```
SENTIMENT_THRESHOLDS = (0.4, 0.7) 
"""The function below will be used to give meaning to our trained model with scores. Label will be determined by the comparison
of score and thereshold values above. 
Label is:
    'Neutral' if 0.4<score<0.7 
    'Negative' if score<=0.4 
    'Positive' if score>=0.7      
"""

def decode_sentiment(score, include_neutral=True):
    label = 'Neutral'
    if score <= SENTIMENT_THRESHOLDS[0]:
        label = 'Negative'
    elif score >= SENTIMENT_THRESHOLDS[1]:
        label = "Positive"

    return label
    
"""This function takes text as input and determine if label of the text is Positive, Negative or Neutral"""    
def predict(text):
    # Tokenize text
    x_test = pad_sequences(tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([text]), maxlen=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
    # Predict score
    score = model.predict([x_test])[0]
    # Decode sentiment
    label = decode_sentiment(score)

    return {"label": label, "score": float(score)}

scores = model.predict(x_test, verbose=1, batch_size=10000) 

y_pred_1d = [decode_sentiment(score) for score in scores]

#User interface to use the program; It takes a text input from the user and print its label

userInput=""
while(userInput!="q"):
    userInput=input("Enter a sentence: \n Press q to quit program ")
    if(userInput=="q"):
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Exiting program...")
    else:    
        print(predict(userInput))
```

**EDIT**

code in train file:

```
model.save('pretrained_model.h5')   # in file train.py
```

code in test file:

```
loaded_model = keras.models.load_model('pretrained_model.h5') # in file test.py
```

And the ERROR is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-961c0ca89c78> in <module>
      4 from tensorflow import keras
      5 
----> 6 loaded_model = keras.models.load_model('pretrained_model.h5') # in file test.py

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\save.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    182     if (h5py is not None and (
    183         isinstance(filepath, h5py.File) or h5py.is_hdf5(filepath))):
--> 184       return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    185 
    186     if sys.version_info >= (3, 4) and isinstance(filepath, pathlib.Path):

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py in load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    174     if model_config is None:
    175       raise ValueError('No model found in config file.')
--> 176     model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
    177     model = model_config_lib.model_from_config(model_config,
    178                                                custom_objects=custom_objects)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. You can use various methods for that but the simplest one is to use **save(filename)** method in keras like:-

```
model.save('pretrained_model.h5')   # in file train.py
```

and to load it you can use the load it you simply use the **load(filename)** method.

```
loaded_model = keras.models.load_model('pretrained_model.h5') # in file test.py
```

**Alternatively:-** 
You can also save your model as json using the following command:-

```
#from file train.py
with open('pretrained_model.json','w') as f:
    f.write(model.to_json())
```

and load you model using following command.

```
# from file test.py
reconstructed_model = keras.models.model_from_json(open('pretrained_model.json','r').read())
```

Comment: I understood, but after loading the model, how can i test and run this pretrained model from an another python file?

Comment: The `loaded_model` object will behave the same way as any keras model. `loaded_model.predict(x_test)`. I've edited the answer a bit I hope it's more clear.

Comment: thank you for your answer. When i try to load the model to the test file it gives an error ": 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'"

Comment: @KaceySmith can you attach the code for loading and the error statement?

Comment: @KaceySmith Perhaps try changing the save call to `model.save('pretrained_model.h5', save_format='h5') `? Maybe it's saving it in the wrong format. Just a guess. It's strange you're getting an error here.

Comment: @Isaac C Way thank you for your answer, I tried your suggestion but it still gives the same error. I think it is about something with "utf-8" but i could not find how to fix this.

Comment: @KaceySmith it seems like a problem with the keras loading code. Maybe update keras and tensorflow if you're using that. The error you're getting happens because decode is being called on a string, which mean that the keras code is thinking the `model_config` should be bytes instead of string. Perhaps there is a compatibility issue with the version of keras you're using and Python or tensorflow. Try updating keras, python, and anything else you're using to the newest versions. I think it's most likely the python version causing the issue but again I'm not sure I can't test it

Comment: @KaceySmith You can try to convert to it to some other form like YAML or json to see if it works.

Comment: @KaceySmith I've edited the answer and added code to convert to json you can check if it works.

Comment: @krypticmouse thank you it solved the error. Now i am trying to run predict method above in my train file but it does not work. How can i run that method?